# Pip Installation - How to lock a python lib version when building a wheel?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, python-wheel, python-cffi

Question: How do I force pip wheel building to use a particular package?

Full background:

I have a project with setup.py with a set of libs with versions locked down.

Libs are something like this (shortened for conciseness):

```
cffi==1.15.0
<some_other_pkg>=1.0.0
<lots of other packages>
```

When **some_other_pkg** installs, pip attempts to build the wheel for this package it uses `cffi==1.15.1`. I would have expected this to use ***1.15.0*** when building the wheel given the above.

This is a problem for me as my server can't run with `cffi==1.15.1`.

How can I instruct pip to use `cffi==1.15.0` in the pip wheel building as part of the pip install requirements.pip ?

Further details:
using python3, virtualenv, pip, setuptools

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this yesterday by doing the following:

1. Creating the venv
2. pip install cibffi==1.15.0
3. Installing my project via: `pip install .` in the dir with the setup.py file.

The above forced the building of wheels to utilise cibffi==1.15.0 instead of the newer version and so no issues relating to missing unix pkg libffi-devel.